# Table creation in install module returns error

Tags: hooks

I am trying to create a table using a custom module in the install file:

```
function leave_tracker_schema() {
  $schema = array();
  $schema['leave_balance'] = array(
    'description' => t('The base table for employee leave balance.'),
    'fields' => array(
      'lid' => array(
        'description' => 'The primary identifier for a row.',
        'type' => 'serial',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE),
      'eid' => array(
        'description' => 'The tocken got from employee data.',
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length' => 255,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => 0),
      'casual' => array(
        'description' => 'The casual leave balanace of employee.',
        'type' => 'int',
        'not null' => TRUE,),
      'sick' => array(
        'description' => 'The sick leave balanace of employee.',
        'type' => 'int',
        'not null' => TRUE,),
      ),
    'indexes' => array(
      'node_changed'        => array('changed'),
      'node_created'        => array('created'),
      ),
    'primary key' => array('lid'),
    ); 
  return $schema;
}'
```

but this returns an error when I install the module

> 'PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1072
>   Key column 'changed' doesn't exist in table: CREATE TABLE
>   {leave_balance} ( `lid` INT unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment COMMENT
>   'The primary identifier for a row.', `eid` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
>   DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'The tocken got from employee data.', `casual` INT
>   NOT NULL COMMENT 'The casual leave balanace of employee.', `sick` INT
>   NOT NULL COMMENT 'The sick leave balanace of employee.', PRIMARY KEY
>   (`lid`), INDEX `node_changed` (`changed`), INDEX `node_created`
>   (`created`) ) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COMMENT 'The
>   base table for employee leave balance.'; Array ( ) in
>   db_create_table() (line 2720 of
>   /var/www/html/cybpedia/includes/database/database.inc).'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `indexes` element you're specifying 2 columns, `changed` & `created`, that don't exist. You need to have these columns added to your `fields` element or remove the indexes.